# Hashing password in Javascript returning undefined result

Tags: javascript, passwords

I will try to be as detailed as possible, I am not comfortable with the ins and outs of Javascript so this might be a painfully basic question.

I need to grab user input, hash it, and then post it.  I am currently using the bCrypt algorithm from MIT, I don't have to use that specifically but it does have to be client-side. (As an aside, I know that hashing things like passwords client-side is not a good idea, I've been reading a lot on SO about that...but for these purposes this is just an exercise).

I can generate the salt, so I'm successfully calling that function from the bCrypt.js file, however I am running into issues with hashing the password.  Previously I was able to get the password hashed, but then could not successfully reference that variable anywhere else or post it.  Now I've messed it all up and can't even get the hash working, it is returning undefined (this is why I need to get into the habit of using version control).

My Code:

```js
var ROUNDS = 10;

// Function grabs username and password from user's input
//
function submitButton() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;

  hashPw(userInput, userName);
}

function result(hash) {
  console.log('hash in callback is ' + hash);
}

function hashPw(old, name) {
  console.log('hashPw called');
  console.log('old password= ' + old);

  var salt = gensalt(ROUNDS);
  hashpw(old, salt, result);
  console.log('Salt= ' + salt)
  console.log('hashed password=');

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hash</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="bcrypt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password: </label>
      <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitButton()">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="callHash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My js:

And it's rather lengthy to post here but this is the bCrypt algorithm I am using: https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt/blob/master/bCrypt.js

An example of the console output I am getting consistently:

```
callHash.js:18 hashPw called
callHash.js:19 old password= tryagain
callHash.js:23 Salt= $2a$10$AwGCCKs5bXa1SNzdKLBytO
callHash.js:24 hashed password=undefined
```

EDIT--
This is what I'm getting over and over, no matter what I change:

```
bcrypt.js:467 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 102ms
```

Thanks so much for any help or suggestions, I did try to research this and troubleshoot a lot before coming for guidance, I've redone the whole thing a couple of times so I think I'm missing something big and obvious here.

Comment: What is `result` in `hashpw(old, salt, result);`?

Comment: @Thijs: `function result(hash){`

Comment: Apparently, the callback isn't called, either.

Comment: `hashpw` doesn't return a result, it is not till `result` is called that you will have your hashed password.

Comment: @Cerbrus, but it is. I tried it and the `result` method does get called.

Comment: What is this `gensalt` function?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I realized my original code was trying to use hashpw() inappropriately since it doesn't return anything, so I fixed that.  But I'm still not getting the hash in the result method.  @Cerbrus the gensalt is in the bCrypt algorithm, I am sucessfully getting a salt from that which thereotically gets added to the hash....although clearly that isn't happening so far

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the async functions of bcrypt.
Either you use the sync functions (genSaltSync and hashSync) or you read a bit about callbacks.
I would suggest the second one wich results in something like:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("B4c0/\/", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB. 
    });
});
```

For more info check the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

Comment: Thank you that already pushes me in the right direction, I was thinking I was running into an async-related issue.  And I'm not well-versed in callbacks so that's spot on.  Question, though, that looks like the nodejs bcrypt function...?  I was thinking I couldn't use that since I assumed, since it's nodejs, it would be server-side.  I've been asked to specifically carry this out client-side, which I'm gathering is not the best way

Comment: I never used it in the frontend, but the pattern stays the same no matter wich library you are using. Perhaps your libarary returns a promise then the callback is placed within the .then() function.